# Images not loading on local view - mixture

Tags: html, liquid, mixture-model

I want to load images stored in respective subdirectories of html file for eg in images/ folder where my index.html file is located.

when i tried to show images with this tag

```
<img src="./images/study.jpg" width="100%" alt="study all time">
```

this works if I crate project to html but does not work on local view.

Am I doing any silly mistake?[image]

Comment: Check the location of the generated html file, the "images" folder shoulb in the same folder as the html.

Comment: Yes it is in same folder.. and its working after transferring into HTMl but in localhost its not working

Comment: you should add a double dot `../images//study.jpg"`

Comment: but that will search in one level up directory and result in error